# Spring batch complaining about BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE does not exist despite having initialized in xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to create a very simple Spring batch project in order to have some hands on understanding of it. I am drying to enter dummy username, passwords in an oracle table called user_details from a csv file.

Following is my `database.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/orcl.168.0.106" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
  </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>

  <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />
  </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

a file describing the job is given as follows `job-report.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="userDetails" class="com.springbatch.model.UserDetails" scope="prototype" />
    <batch:job id="userDetailsJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="oracleItemWriter"
            commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:csv/cred.csv" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="USER_NAME,PASSWORD"></property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="userDetails" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
             <![CDATA[        
                insert into user_details(USER_NAME,PASSWORDS) 
            values (:USER_NAME, :PASSWORDS)
            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

My application class looks something like this

```
package com.springbatch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   "config/database.xml", 
                "config/job-report.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("userDetailsJob");
        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Batch Done");
    }

}
```

User Details model is as follows

```
package com.springbatch.model;

public class UserDetails {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



}
```

My `pom.xml` file is below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springbatch</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBatch</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
  <spring.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>8</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

But I keep running into this error below,

```
May 17, 2019 5:45:33 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher afterPropertiesSet
INFO: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:699)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:101)
    at com.springbatch.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:765)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:921)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3687)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 38, Sql = SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = :1  and JOB_KEY = :2 , OriginalSql = SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 36 more
Batch Done
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, what am I missing here, will deeply appreciate your input on this.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your config other than the order of scripts in the `jdbc:initialize-database` element. I'm not sure if the declaration order matters but if it does, then the issue would be that `schema-drop-oracle10g.sql` is executed after `schema-oracle10g.sql` hence dropping all tables. Can you try to invert them and see if things are better?

Comment: Yes, I swapped the positions of the two statements but I get the same error `Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql]: DROP TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: That's different, now the script tries to drop a table which does not exist. I think Spring Batch should use something like `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in the drop script but this is not supported in Oracle AFAIK. Since the tables do not exist, have you tried to use only the table creation script?

Comment: It worked by manually running creation script but now its compalaining about `No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'USER_NAME': Invalid property 'USER_NAME' of bean class`. I saw no inputs are being supplied `Job: [FlowJob: [name=userDetailsJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]`. I am using a csv file for passing input params called cred.csv.

Comment: That's because the `names` property of `DelimitedLineTokenizer` should be set to the fields in the target class, not the fields of the table. Update your config to `<property name="names" value="username, password"></property>` instead of `<property name="names" value="USER_NAME,PASSWORD"></property>` and it should work fine. I guess your `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Following changes in bean id oracleItemWriter ` <property name="sql">
   <value>
    <![CDATA[        
             insert into user_details(USER_NAME,PASSWORD) 
   values (:user_name, :password)
            ]]>
   </value>` and as you suggested following changes in `<bean  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
      <property name="names" value="user_name,password"></property>
     </bean>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the modified `job-report.xml` that solved my problem, also, I had to create oracle batch tables manually by running the script provided in batch core.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="userDetails" class="com.springbatch.model.UserDetails" scope="prototype" />
    <batch:job id="userDetailsJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="oracleItemWriter"
            commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:CSV/cred.csv" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="user_name,password"></property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="userDetails" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
             <![CDATA[        
                insert into user_details(USER_NAME,PASSWORD) 
            values (:user_name, :password)
            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```